# VSCode unable to find settings.json on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to change the theme, I get an error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/admin/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json'

If I try and open `settings.json` from the link in the VSCode settings area, it won't open at all.

If, from the terminal, I do `vim "/Users/admin/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json"`, it opens what seems like a blank or new file. If I type `:wq` vim shows me the following error:

> "~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json" E166: Can't open linked file for writing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, here's what I did. I went to `~/Library/Application Support/Code/user` and did `ls -la`. That showed me this,

```
drwxr-xr-x    7 admin  staff   224 Apr 14 18:29 .
drwx------   33 admin  staff  1056 Apr 14 18:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x    4 admin  staff   128 Apr 14 18:27 globalStorage
-rw-r--r--    1 admin  staff   103 Dec  3 14:18 keybindings.json
lrwxr-xr-x    1 admin  staff    42 Feb 13 10:16 settings.json -> /Users/admin/dotfiles/vscode/settings.json
drwxr-xr-x    2 admin  staff    64 Jun 11  2018 snippets
drwxr-xr-x  109 admin  staff  3488 Apr 14 18:28 workspaceStorage
```

So I tried to look at the file `settings.json` was linked to, but the whole path starting at `dotfiles` didn't even exist. So instead I deleted `settings.json` (`rm settings.json`) and made it again using `touch settings.json`. After that I haven't had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application Support/Code/user
touch ~/Library/Application Support/Code/user/settings.json
```

Now preferences are retained by my golang fyne program. But there's nothing inside settings.json. Where are the preferences being saved?